# Minimum distance between Point and LineString

Tags: python, shapely

I'm experimenting a [different solution](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#nearest-points) to find a point on a line that identify a minimum distance between the line and another point not on the line. I have a point and a line:

```
p_not_on_linestring = Point(-12.973622, 54.458466)
linestring = LineString([(-0.446866298572111, -1.1810037890834053), (-36.57919844025919, 19.94938832911169)])
```

I started finding the minimum distance:

```
min_distance = p_not_on_linestring.distance(linestring)
```

After that I builded a buffer used for find the intersection between this circle and my line.

```
buffer_min_distance = p_not_on_linestring.buffer(min_distance)
point_min_distance = buffer_min_distance.intersection(linestring)
```

Since previously I found the minimum distance I expect that there is at least one point into the intersection, but I see

> LINESTRING EMPTY

I think this result isn't correct. Or my line of reasoning is not correct?

[image]

Comment: I believe there are couple of things happening here. One is just the inherent issue of floating point values. Another is that shapely might be expecting that the intersection between a `Polygon` and a `LineString` should be a `LineString`, not a `Point`. Not sure how to fix it, but that's my guess of what the problem is. Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use the `shapely.ops.nearest_points` method?

Comment: Floating point problem is very annoying! The intersection between a circle and a line can be a segment if the line is secant or a point if the line is tangent. Based on this reasoning from geometry I think that, when a line is tangent to a circle, the output can't be a LineString but a Point. Anyway I use `nearest_points` without problem. This question was born from my experiment. Sometimes I try to experiment new way to do something only for curiosity :)